# Rails 3 with Devise - Unauthorized redirect with jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, devise

Application controller:

I use view inheritance instead of a different format (like `:mobile`)

```
before_filter :subdomain_view_path

def subdomain_view_path
  prepend_view_path "app/views/mobile" if request.server_name.include?("mobile") || request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|iPad/
end
```

Shows controller

```
class ShowsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

When I go directly to /shows in my browser, I get redirected to the login page correctly.
However, I get a `401 Unauthorized` when clicking a link (ajax) to that page.

How can I solve this? It would be cool to keep this ajax loading of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in you application.js may help you:

```
// Set up a global AJAX error handler to handle the 401
// unauthorized responses. If a 401 status code comes back,
// the user is no longer logged-into the system and can not
// use it properly.
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {

            // Redirect the to the login page.
            location.href = "/login";

        }
    }
});
```

Source: http://rubythings.blogspot.de/2011/10/ajax-redirects-with-devise.html